# SAPUI5 i18n oBundle.setText()

Tags: internationalization, sapui5

I am working on an SAPUI5 application. We are using i18n localization concept wherein we have declared properties for all static texts on our application and assigned values to them that can be used for example like this:

```
var oButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button();
oButton.setText(oBundle.getText("LOGIN_BUTTON_NAME"));
```

Now I have a requirement where certain label texts have to be updated dynamically based on user settings. And these texts are defined in the i18n bundle.  So I am looking for something like:

```
//Update i18n bundle
oBundle.setText("USERNAME_LABEL", "Username");
//Use updated value
oLabel.setText(oBundle.getText("USERNAME_LABEL"));
```

But I couldn't find a `setText()` method anywhere.

Any help will be deeply acknowledged.

Comment: arent the bundle values constants? why not use a formatter function to change the labels binding dynamically

Comment: Hi Jasper, first of all thanks for replying. Well, actually you are right. They indeed are meant to be constants. The scenario that I have at hand is: there are seven labels that should show the days of the week. But there is a setting that allows a user to toggle between start of week as Monday or Sunday.

Comment: Anyway, I have put some workaround in place now to solve my problem without having to bother about changing the "constants". So guess I am fine if no answers are posted.

Comment: I might have misunderstood, but this sounds like you're pushing logic and data to your labels. The "MONDAY" label should be "Monday" ("Montag", "Lundi" etc) regardless of what the user-specific start-of-week is.

Comment: qmacro, you are right there. But the scenario I was looking at was that if the first label shows "Monday" ("Montag", "Lundi" etc) when Monday is start of week then the same should show "Sunday" ("Zondag", "Dimanche" etc) when Sunday is start of week. But I guess changing a constant from code doesn't make sense. I have implemented a workaround that appears pretty clean at the moment. So thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that I'm late :D

You should not do this, because the i18n resources are static text.

The best way is if you define an extra JSONModel
and load the data which you want to change from your bundle in there.

If you have a label like:

```
<Label text="{/USERNAME_LABEL}" />
```

You could use the following code:

```
var oModel = new JSONModel({
    USERNAME_LABEL: oBundle.getText("USERNAME_LABEL")
});

oLabel.setModel(oModel);
```

Now every time you want to update the text, you can do:

```
var oData = oModel.getData();
oData.USERNAME_LABEL = "bla...";
oModel.refresh();
```

and the view will automatically update.